# Django web service stack and concepts questions

Tags: python, django, nginx, asynchronous, server

I need to develop a web service with RESTful API on Django. I would be grateful if someone could clarify a few questions and point me in the right direction.

It has to connect to a remote database and perform long queries and then return the rows to a user (I plan on returning csv files)
I chose Django as a framework, but I am a bit lost with all the things I read

1. Since queries take a long time to finish , the service should somehow work in async. The async concept in regards to web services especially in connection to Django is really complicated to grasp.
   Would using new Django 3.x async features be enough for this task?
   I've read about Celery the queue manager that is supposed to provide some degree of parallelisation (am I correct on this?)
   I've also read about nginx + wsgi + Django. Should I go with that?
2. In regards to nginx and other web servers. Am I correct in understanding that Django in itself can function as a web server, but nginx can be used to somehow better the performance of a Django application?
3. Should I use "django rest framework" for the task?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your question: "Django in itself can function as a web server?":

Django's http server service is for developer's convenience and needs only. The developer can test the application in easy way. In no circumstances is Django's http server service appropriate to be used in production environment, not just  because of performance.

Further:
Your questions regarding concept:

there are "hundred options" how you can  meet the project requirements. If this is a serious project (not just for exercise purpose), in the light of your questions, the only answer is: use a technology you are best familiar with.